# Aplicação roda no eclipse mas não roda no Intelij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jboss-weld

Estou migrando do eclipse para o Intelij e minha aplicação roda normal no eclipse, e quando faço deploy no servidor, mas não roda no intelij.

Não tem nenhuma mensagem de erro, só de log.

```
package br.com.ramires.pac;

import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.port;
import static spark.Spark.post;
import static spark.Spark.put;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.events.ContainerInitialized;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.BucaPorCPFHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.BuscaColicitacoesHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.BuscaFormacoesHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.CheckCodeHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.CheckEmailHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.LoginHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.RegisterColicitacoesHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.RegisterServidorHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.handlers.UpdateServidorHandler;
import br.com.ramires.pac.utils.Configuration;

public class App {

    @Inject
    private Gson gson;

    @Inject
    private BucaPorCPFHandler bucaPorCPFHandler;

    @Inject
    private CheckCodeHandler checkCodeHandler;

    @Inject
    private CheckEmailHandler checkEmailHandler;

    @Inject
    private RegisterServidorHandler registerServidorHandler;

    @Inject
    private LoginHandler loginHandler;

    @Inject
    private UpdateServidorHandler updateServidorHandler;

    @Inject
    private BuscaFormacoesHandler buscaFormacoesHandler;

    @Inject
    Configuration configuration;

    @Inject
    private BuscaColicitacoesHandler buscaSolicitacoesHandler;

    @Inject
    private RegisterColicitacoesHandler registerSolicitacoesHandler;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        SeContainerInitializer container = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
        container.initialize();
    }

    public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized initialized) {
        port(getPort());

        post(Router.cpf, bucaPorCPFHandler, gson::toJson);

        post(Router.checkCode, checkCodeHandler, gson::toJson);

        post(Router.checkEmail, checkEmailHandler, gson::toJson);

        post(Router.servidor, registerServidorHandler, gson::toJson);

        post(Router.login, loginHandler, gson::toJson);

        put(Router.servidor, updateServidorHandler, gson::toJson);

        get(Router.formacoes, buscaFormacoesHandler, gson::toJson);

        get(Router.solicitacoes, buscaSolicitacoesHandler, gson::toJson);
        post(Router.solicitacoes, registerSolicitacoesHandler, gson::toJson);

        configuration.execute();
    }

    private int getPort() {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        if (processBuilder.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
            final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(processBuilder.environment().get("PORT"));
            return PORT;
        }
        return 4567;
    }

}
```

E os logs são:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50860:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/java_workspace/pac/target/classes:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/sparkjava/spark-core/2.7.2/spark-core-2.7.2.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-http-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-util-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-io-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-webapp-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-xml-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-security-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-server/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-server-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-common/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-common-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-client/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-client-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-servlet/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-servlet-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/websocket-api/9.4.8.v20171121/websocket-api-9.4.8.v20171121.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21/slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.12.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.3.Final/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.0/classmate-1.3.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-hikaricp/5.2.10.Final/hibernate-hikaricp-5.2.10.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.1/HikariCP-2.6.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.1/postgresql-42.2.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-tools/5.2.8.Final/hibernate-tools-5.2.8.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.10.1/ant-1.10.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.10.1/ant-launcher-1.10.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.23/freemarker-2.3.23.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.12.2/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.12.2.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.resources/3.12.0/org.eclipse.core.resources-3.12.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.expressions/3.6.0/org.eclipse.core.expressions-3.6.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.runtime/3.13.0/org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.13.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.osgi/3.12.100/org.eclipse.osgi-3.12.100.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.equinox.common/3.9.0/org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.9.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.jobs/3.9.3/org.eclipse.core.jobs-3.9.3.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.equinox.registry/3.7.0/org.eclipse.equinox.registry-3.7.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences/3.7.0/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences-3.7.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.contenttype/3.6.0/org.eclipse.core.contenttype-3.6.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.equinox.app/1.3.400/org.eclipse.equinox.app-1.3.400.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.filesystem/1.7.0/org.eclipse.core.filesystem-1.7.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.text/3.6.100/org.eclipse.text-3.6.100.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/platform/org.eclipse.core.commands/3.9.0/org.eclipse.core.commands-3.9.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-email/1.5/commons-email-1.5.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.6/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/jboss/weld/se/weld-se-shaded/3.0.4.Final/weld-se-shaded-3.0.4.Final.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-data-module-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-data-module-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/core/deltaspike-core-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-core-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-partial-bean-module-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-partial-bean-module-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-data-module-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-data-module-impl-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-core-impl-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-partial-bean-module-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-partial-bean-module-impl-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-proxy-module-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-proxy-module-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-proxy-module-impl-asm5/1.8.0/deltaspike-proxy-module-impl-asm5-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-jpa-module-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-jpa-module-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/cdictrl/deltaspike-cdictrl-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-cdictrl-api-1.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.187/h2-1.4.187.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.11/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-core/2.2.11/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.9.0/jjwt-0.9.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.9/jackson-databind-2.8.9.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.9/jackson-core-2.8.9.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.23.0/google-api-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.23.0/google-oauth-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.23.0/google-http-client-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/httpclient-4.0.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.23.0/google-http-client-jackson2-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty/1.23.0/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client-java6/1.23.0/google-oauth-client-java6-1.23.0.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev72-1.23.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev72-1.23.0.jar br.com.ramires.pac.App
    objc[19023]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x103ae84c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x103b6c4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:12 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
    INFO: WELD-000900: 3.0.4 (Final)
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:12 AM org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.EnvironmentPropertyConfigSourceProvider <init>
    INFO: Custom config found by DeltaSpike. Name: 'META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties', URL: 'jar:file:/Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl-1.8.0.jar!/META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties'
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:12 AM org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer initProjectStage
    INFO: Computed the following DeltaSpike ProjectStage: Production
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:12 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory create
    INFO: WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:13 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
    INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.interceptor.GlobalInterceptorExtension.promoteInterceptors(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.exclude.extension.ExcludeExtension.vetoBeans(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.message.MessageBundleExtension.detectInterfaces(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.config.ConfigurationExtension.findDynamicConfigurationBeans(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.apache.deltaspike.partialbean.impl.PartialBeanBindingExtension.findInvocationHandlerBindings(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations
    INFO: WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.apache.deltaspike.data.impl.RepositoryExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<X>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.logging.ValidatorLogger lambda$static$6
    WARN: WELD-001478: Interceptor class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.throttling.ThrottledInterceptor is enabled for the application and for the bean archive /Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-core-impl-1.8.0.jar. It will only be invoked in the @Priority part of the chain.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.logging.ValidatorLogger lambda$static$6
    WARN: WELD-001478: Interceptor class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.lock.LockedInterceptor is enabled for the application and for the bean archive /Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-core-impl-1.8.0.jar. It will only be invoked in the @Priority part of the chain.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.logging.ValidatorLogger lambda$static$6
    WARN: WELD-001478: Interceptor class org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.future.FutureableInterceptor is enabled for the application and for the bean archive /Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/core/deltaspike-core-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-core-impl-1.8.0.jar. It will only be invoked in the @Priority part of the chain.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.logging.ValidatorLogger lambda$static$6
    WARN: WELD-001478: Interceptor class org.apache.deltaspike.proxy.util.EnableInterceptorsInterceptor is enabled for the application and for the bean archive /Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-proxy-module-api/1.8.0/deltaspike-proxy-module-api-1.8.0.jar. It will only be invoked in the @Priority part of the chain.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:14 AM org.jboss.weld.logging.ValidatorLogger lambda$static$6
    WARN: WELD-001478: Interceptor class org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor is enabled for the application and for the bean archive /Users/ramiresmoreira/.m2/repository/org/apache/deltaspike/modules/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl/1.8.0/deltaspike-jpa-module-impl-1.8.0.jar. It will only be invoked in the @Priority part of the chain.
    Jun 08, 2018 12:25:15 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
    INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container 854851a4-4564-41ee-a1a1-41972df1aa33 initialized
    Weld SE container 854851a4-4564-41ee-a1a1-41972df1aa33 shut down by shutdown hook
```

Comment: Como vc tá rodando a aplicação, exatamente? Dá uma olhada nesse cara aqui. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266860/error-when-try-run-weld-se-applicaton-weld-se-container-cannot-be-initialized

Comment: A forma mais simples e unificada de fazer a aplicação coexistir no eclipse e no intellij é usando Maven, ai vc importa como Projeto Maven

Comment: estou usando maven, e o projeto foi importado como maven, minha aplicação usa um embed server que é o Jetty e estou usando o weld-se http://weld.cdi-spec.org que é uma implementação do CDI para ambientes JavaSE